# Unable to locate packages on Linux Debian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, python-2.x, putty

I am new to using Linux Debian. I am trying to run a python 2 file on a raspberry pi through ssh. However, I can't import modules through PuTTY. Whenever I try to import a module, I see this error:

```
~/Coding/raspberry pi/python 2 $ apt-get install keyboard
E: unable to locate package keyboard
```

I tried `sudo-apt get update` and `sudo-apt get upgrade` but it still gives the same error. I found a couple of answers such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164481/unable-to-install-packages-from-raspbian-repo) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607792/cant-locate-keytouch) but none of them worked. Does anyone know why it can't locate modules? Should I try installing something like pip for this?

Comment: Refer to this askubuntu [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using pip as the root. Because the keyboard package uses the keyboard, it requires the root password.